# View only updates on page reload?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So, I am developing a very simple MEAN stack CRUD app which lets the user add, edit, delete posts and display them on the same page. I am not using routing currently, and have two components,

1) post-create
2) posts-list

I'm using a service to pass data from post-create to posts-list.

I understand that posts-list component is initialized initally when the app is loaded, which obviously calls the ngOnInit() of posts-list, and the data is fetched from the server.

I want the 'posts' array in the posts-list to be updated when the 'Save' button is clicked in the post-create component, which would obviously update the view of the posts-list component, instead of updating it when the page is reloaded and ngOnInit() is called again.

I just can't figure out how would I get the updated data without reloading the page. Thanks

**The service:**

**post.service.ts**

```
import { Post } from './posts.interface';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class PostsService {

  uri = 'http://localhost:3000/api/posts';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
  return this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this.uri}`);
  }

  addPost(post: Post): Observable<Post> {
  return this.http.post<Post>(`${this.uri}`, post);
  }
```

**post-create.component.html**

```
<mat-card>
  <form>
    <mat-form-field>
     <input matInput type="text" name="title" minlength="3"
     [(ngModel)]="post.title" placeholder="Post Title">
    </mat-form-field>

   <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput rows="4" name="content" 
    [(ngModel)]="post.content"
    placeholder="Post Content">
    </textarea>
   </mat-form-field>

   <button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="save-btn" 
   (click)="onAddPost()">Save Post</button>
 </form>
</mat-card>
```

**post-create.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../posts.interface';
import { PostsService } from '../posts.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-posts-create',
templateUrl: './posts-create.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./posts-create.component.css']
})

export class PostsCreateComponent implements OnInit {

post: Post = {} as Post;

constructor(public postsService: PostsService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

  onAddPost() {
  this.postsService.addPost(this.post).subscribe(post => {
  this.post = post;
  });
 }
}
```

**posts-list.component.html**

```
<mat-accordion multi="true">
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">

    <mat-expansion-panel-header>{{post.title}}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>{{post.content}}</p>

  <mat-action-row>
   <button mat-button color="primary">EDIT</button>
   <button mat-button color="warn">DELETE</button>
  </mat-action-row>

 </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

**posts-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../posts.interface';
import { PostsService } from '../posts.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-posts-list',
templateUrl: './posts-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./posts-list.component.css']
})

export class PostsListComponent implements OnInit {

  posts: Post[];

  constructor(public postsService: PostsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  this.getAllPosts();
  }

  getAllPosts() {
  this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe((posts: Post[]) => {
    this.posts = posts;
    console.log(this.posts);
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [comunicate between both parent and child components](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), one way to do this is to use [eventemitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) with @Output decorator:

First, edit your child component `post-create.component.ts` to add the EventEmitter to emit events to your parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
...

export class PostsCreateComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() emitNewPost = new EventEmitter();    
...

onAddPost() {
  this.postsService.addPost(this.post).subscribe(post => {
    this.post = post;
    // Here we emit the event with your new post
    this.emitNewPost.emit(this.post);
  });
 }
```

Then in the parent component html `posts-list.component.html` you bind in the html, notice we use `emitNewPost` as is our property defined by the `@Output` decorator:

```
    ...
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts" (emitNewPost)='addNewPost($event)'>
    ...
```

Last, add the method in your parents ts file `posts-list.component.ts`, addNewPost will now be triggered every time a new post is added:

```
public addNewPost(post) {
  this.posts.push(post);
}
```

Comment: I've read about Input and Output. How would I do it with services? I've read about "Subject" and have read the docs, but I'm confused as to how to implement it in my code.

Comment: If you want to do it from your service you could use BehaviorSubject, which always holds the last value, subject does not. but since you are subscribing in your component, I would go with EventEmitter for this use case in particular, I do not see the benefit of holding it in the service.

Comment: Understood. Btw, your given solution is not working. Still have to refresh the page to update the view.